# Is it true that freckles have zero potential for malignant transformation?

Tags: dermatology, cancer, practice-of-medicine, melanoma

This New York City dermatologist called [Dr. Bobby Buca](https://www.thedermspecs.com/authors/dr-bobby-buka/) on [this web page](https://www.thedermspecs.com/blog/how-to-tell-the-difference-between-a-mole-and-a-freckle/) says:

"Freckles and moles have two things in common: there is a genetic tendency to get them, and both are darker than the surrounding skin.

However, there is one big difference. Freckles have zero potential for malignant transformation."

On the other hand, [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRzKnWz-r0AhWWSGwGHV7qB5wQFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.medicinenet.com%2Ffreckles%2Farticle.htm&usg=AOvVaw13GQGgDnVnQq7rOBssV0i3) says "Unusual-appearing freckles may become malignant skin cancer."

Furthermore, [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj69LCZ1er0AhXvyzgGHeSLBX8QFnoECAYQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcancer.ca%2Fen%2Fcancer-information%2Fwhat-is-cancer%2Fhow-cancer-starts-grows-and-spreads&usg=AOvVaw1A_tzObuH7zJpHYgkZ85J7) says "Although there are many different types of cancer, they all start because of cells that are growing abnormally and out of control. **Cancer can start in any cell in the body**." The bold font is in the original.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is much medical science here, just interpretation of language and writing.

"Freckles have zero potential for malignant transformation" is not a statement of scientific fact, it is an example of rhetorical hyperbole. The statement is not intended to be taken literally, but to emphasize a distinction between moles and freckles.

Similarly, "Unusual-appearing freckles may become malignant skin cancer" is mixing a colloquial definition with a medical one. An "unusual-appearing freckle" is possibly not a freckle at all, but rather cancer that a patient may dismiss as "just a freckle". The statement should not be taken literally in conjunction with the first one.